# sshfs mount, sudo gets permission denied

Tags: ssh, sudo, sshfs

I am using `sshfs` to mount a folder with some python projects over ssh to my `~/` directory.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/mount/my-projects
$ sshfs user@example.com:/home/user/my-projects ~/mount/my-projects
```

I can perform most commands as could be expected:

```
$ ls ~/mount/my-projects
some-python-project
```

But I if I try to do anything with `sudo`, it fails with permission denied:

```
$ sudo ls ~/mount/my-projects
ls: cannot access /home/user/mount/my-projects: Permission denied
```

What I'm actually trying to accomplish is to test a python package installation script on my local machine:

```
$ cd ~/mount/my-projects/some-python-project
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I believe you need use the `allow_other` option to sshfs.  In order to do this, you should call it with sudo, as follows:-

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other user@myserver:/home/user/myprojects ~/mount/myprojects
```

Without this option, only the user who ran sshfs can access the mount.  This is a fuse restriction.  More info is available by typing `man fuse`.

You should also note that (on Ubuntu at least) you need to be a member of the 'fuse' group, otherwise the command above will complain about not being able to access `/etc/fuse.conf` when ran without 'sudo'.

Comment: Good first answer!

Comment: See also the `allow_root` option to allow `root` only. Please note however that those options are restricted to root by default unless you add a `user_allow_other` line to `/etc/fuse.conf`.

Answer (score 12):

`sshfs` is a userland process, so there is no need to run it with `sudo`.

If you do run it as sudo and use SSH key authentication, then the key will be searched under `/root/.ssh` and *not* under your user's `/home/myuser/.ssh`.

The same applies to `~/.ssh/config` file which `sshfs` is capable of using.

If you have a `~/.ssh/config` like:

```bash
Host remotehost
    HostName 111.22.33.44
    User root
    Port 1234
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

then you could mount your remote host as a normal user with:

```bash
sshfs remotehost: local_dir
```

To run under root you could append `-o IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa` to the 'raw' `sshfs` command, or to create `/root/.ssh/config` with the full path to your user's SSH key:

```bash
Host remotehost
    HostName 111.22.33.44
    User root
    Port 1234
    IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now `sshfs remotehost: local_dir` will also work under root.

> <sup>With your `.ssh/config` in place you can copy entire folders between the hosts with (remote to local) `scp -r remotehost:remotedir localdir` or (local to remote) `scp -r localdir remotehost:remotedir`, so for a single one-off operation, you might not even need `sshfs`.</sup>
>
> <sup>If you use a relative remote path as in `remotehost:remotedir` then `remotedir` will be relative to the user's home folder, i.e. `remotehost:remotedir` is equivalent to `remotehost:/home/myuser/remotedir`</sup>

Comment: OP does mount the filesystem as normal user. The problem arises with the need to access files on that filesystem from a root context.

Answer (score 8):

What solved the problem for me was adding the `allow_other` option to the command like so:

```
$ sshfs -o allow_other user@example.com:/home/user/my-projects ~/mount/my-projects
```

then you might get the error:

> option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf
> to solve that head to /etc/fuse.conf with your favorite text editor and uncomment (delete the # behind) `user_allow_other`

If that solved the problem and you could run `sshfs` successfully, great! If not you should try adding your user to the fuse group by this command:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G fuse mark
```

and if it results in error saying fuse group doesn't exist you can easily create that group by:

```
$ sudo groupadd fuse
```

Comment: `sudo groupadd fuse`, not mynewgroup, then either run the `usermod` again or edit `/etc/group` and add the user's name on the end of the fuse line

Comment: Also, `sudo usermod -a -G fuse mark`, not `mark fuse`