# Why can't www-data access an sshfs mount?

Tags: debian, python, fstab, sshfs, web

I have made an sshfs mount as follows (33 is the uid of the `www-data`). Listing the folders and files shows them as having read and execute access for `www-data`. But when my application running as `www-data` tries to access the mount I get a permission error.

**/etc/fstab**

```
example.com:/remote/folder/ /local/folder fuse.sshfs ro,uid=33,gid=33 0 0
```

I get the same permission error if I do the following:

```
sudo -u www-data python
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('/local/folder')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `allow_other` permission to your sshfs mount declaration. Otherwise only the user who performs the mount can access it, even if the file permissions are correct.

**/etc/fstab**

```
example.com:/remote/folder/ /local/folder fuse.sshfs ro,uid=33,gid=33,allow_other 0 0
```

Source: [sshfs mount, sudo gets permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59685)
(similar issue with root instead of www-data)